# How to send and receive data and notification from ASP.NET server to Android app and vise versa?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I want to send notification from ASP.NET server to Android App and meanwhile I need to send data and also I need to send back data and notification to the ASP.NET server from Android app. And I know for this to happen we need GCM but I do not know how to implement,even after so much of googling so please can anybody help me in this regard.

Any answer(solution to the problem) is appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asp.net webapi to get/post data.http://www.asp.net/web-api

From android application you can call this web api and get and send data. There is you tube video for that. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQ8Mu7-s_Xk

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer but having the latest method. Use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). You can send notification/data to apps and you can even manage the coming data very easily in android. Just comment here if anybody wants ASP.net code for sending data through firebase cloud messaging system.